# How to push new branch to remote repository with tracking option

Tags: git

I am working on a local branch (feature1) created from mainline branch. I would like to push this local branch to remote repository. How to achieve this in git along with tracking option.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Push with the `-u` option:

```
git push -u origin <branch>
```

`-u`, short for `--set-upstream`, that is set the upstream in `origin` to the `<branch>` name. If you omit the branch name, the local branch name is used instead. Full story on [Git's documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push).

Comment: That’s assuming “origin” is the name of the OPs remote…

Answer (score 0):

You would have created a feature branch from mainstream branch by

```
git checkout -b <branch>
```

So you can push this local branch to server by using below command. -u option is to set the upstream for your branch.

```
git push -u origin <branch>
```

This will push the local branch to remote.

Going forward, keep on add/edit the files in this branch and commit

```
git add <file>
git commit -m "message to commit"
```

then just push your changes, without -u option.

```
git push origin <branch>
```

Comment: After the initial use of `-u`, a simple `git push` would suffice (without the `«remotename» «branchname»` suffix).